# Comparing last group of IP Addresses and appending missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following IPv4 IPAddresses in Table A:

```
IPAddress1   | IPaddress2
10.20.30.91  | 10.20.30.9
63.90.84.45  | 63.90.84.45
10.5.5.100   | 10.5.5.10
```

I want to check the last digits/group after the last dot (**.**) separator. For example, in the first record, I have the bits ending in 91 and 9 respectively for IPAddress1 and IPAddress2. In IPAddress2, the '1' got cut off. I want to write T-SQL to compare these last values and in cases where the 1 (or whatever value it is missing - in record 3 it is missing a '0') got cut off, append the 1 to it using Update statement and Replace function.

I tried the getting the index of the last dot (**.**) using PATINDEX function but because there is more than one occurrence of the dot (**.**), it returns **0**:

```
select PATINDEX('.', IPAddress1) from TableA
```

Returns:

```
0
```

Ideally what I had in mind was doing the following:

string explanation = Starting position is not definitive since some values hold -> .XX some .XXX before the last value/group

string length_expression = 3 since 255 is the max value that an IP group can hold.

```
update TableA
set IPAddress2 = replace(IPAddress2, SUBSTRING(IPAddress2, start_expression , length_expression, string_replacement)
where (len(IPaddress2)=11) or (len(IPaddress2)=12)
```

The where clause basically looks for IPs that have length 11 or 12 then it means they are missing values in the end.

I am using SQL Server as a DBMS.

Comment: Why not just update: `IPAddress2  = IPAddress1 `?

Comment: So, IPAddress1 and IPAddress2 should be identical?

Comment: No they aren't identical. That was the first thing I thought of

Comment: 10.98.55.216 - IPAddress1
10.146.55.216 - IPAddress2. This is from my actual data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the `LEFT`, `CHARINDEX` and `REVERSE` to get the part of IPAddress2 before the last `.`, and `RIGHT`, `CHARINDEX` and `REVERSE` to get the part of IPAddress1 after the last `.`.
I've also used `PARSENAME` in the where clause to only update the records where the last part of IPAddress2 is different then the last part of IPAddress1.

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    IPAddress1 varchar(15), 
    IPaddress2 varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES
('10.20.30.91', '10.20.30.9'),
('63.90.84.45', '63.90.84.45'),
('10.5.5.100', '10.5.5.10')
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET IPAddress2 = LEFT(IPAddress2, LEN(IPAddress2) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(IPAddress2))) + 
                 RIGHT(IPAddress1, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(IPAddress1)))
WHERE PARSENAME(IPAddress2, 1) <> PARSENAME(IPAddress1, 1)
```

Test:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
```

Results:

```
IPAddress1      IPaddress2
10.20.30.91     10.20.30.91
63.90.84.45     63.90.84.45
10.5.5.100      10.5.5.100
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @Zohar Peled . What I also like about your solution is that it ignores the IP set where there aren't any missing values.

Answer (score 1):

TRY:  This is also good with `STUFF`

```
UPDATE t SET IPAddress2 = STUFF(IPaddress2 , 
                            (LEN(IPaddress2) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(IPaddress2), 1)+2) , 
                                LEN(Parsename(IPAddress2, 1)) ,parsename(IPAddress1,1)) 
FROM #tmp t
WHERE PARSENAME(IPAddress1, 1) <> PARSENAME(IPAddress2, 1)
```

Comment: Works just as well :-) @Suraz

Answer (score 0):

You can use parsename function of sql server:

```
select parsename(Ipaddressv4,1) , Parsename(Ipaddressv4another, 1)
```

By this function you can retrieve values of 4th part of IP. You can use that for updates...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the last digits of the IP address using the following:

```
SELECT RIGHT(IpAddress,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IpAddress))-1)
```